# FirebaseX APNS Token Null

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

we setup everything as described in the Medium Link for setting up APNS with Cordova FirebaseX. [Medium Link](https://medium.com/@felipepucinelli/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-your-cordova-application-using-firebase-69fac067e821)

Also we used the FirebaseX Demo application. [Demo Application](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex-test) where a click on "Get APNS token" leaves us with "null" as a result. A "Get FCM ID" returns a valid device token. We don't receive APNS background messages, because of the missing APNS token.

It doesn't matter if we use a real device or simulator, the APNS field stays null.

We tried manual setting a provisioning profile and importing p12 certificates development/production to Firebase. Our next try was to go with the newer version, with a p8 certificate and automatic signing of the app, also there we had no luck.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong in our setup, we tried literally anything to get this to work. We followed all instructions exactly, even multiple times.

We use the same versions as the demo application 1:1, changed from their bundle id to ours, and replaced both Firebase configuration files from our Firebase console setup.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

We finally fixed it.
There was no problem with APNS configuration.

**If you test your code with an iPhone, which has never had a sim card inserted, then you don't get an APNS token.**

After putting in a sim card we got an APNS token, even if we remove it later. Thank you Apple.